# How to convert time and date to the sentences format in C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, date-conversion

For example the program gets time and date from the system
Date : 17/05/2018
Time: 20:15:55

Output
Date: seventeenth of may two thousand and eighteen
Time: twenty past fifteen

Can i use strftime?

Comment: No, you cannot use `strftime()`. [See the manual page for details on what it can do](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html).

Comment: So, what should I do now ?

Comment: You need to write the code yourself. There is no standard library that does this AFAIK.

Comment: either funny coincidence or you are taking the same course as the user who asked this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50371988/what-should-i-do-if-i-want-to-change-date-and-time-format-to-the-word-in-c#comment87759800_50371988

Comment: @user463035818 Comments deleted.

Comment: OP ? What do you mean about OP?

Comment: @Mochni OP = [Original Poster](https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/O/op_original_poster.html). I.e. you.

Answer (score 0):

There is not library in c or c++ that does that, but this can be done easily manually. You can create a char array with 31 days, 24 hours, etc. Only problem could be with years, but i suppose that you won't need thousands of years for your application.

You can see basic example with hours and minutes [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-given-time-words/).